# AngularFireAuth user state clearing on route change

Tags: angular, authentication, observable

it seems I have hit a wall when in my understanding of observables, AngularFireAuth and firebase authentication. Here is a snippet of my auth service

```
export class AuthService {


user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
      private db: AngularFirestore,
      private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      ) { 

  this.user$ = fireAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      };
    })
   );

}
```

This has worked fine for me with my login and logout methods I have in the header. I am able to subscribe with the async pipe and display a login button if the user is logged out and some user info if the are logged in.

Header.component.html

```
<div *ngIf='!(auth.user$ | async )'>
    <button 
        class="login"
        (click)="openModal()"
        > 
        Login
    </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf='auth.user$ | async as user'>
    <h3>Welcome, {{ firstName( user.displayName) }}! </h3>
    <img [src]='user.photoURL' 
         class='profile'
         *ngIf='user.photoURL'>
    <button (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Now I have created a shipping form in my checkout that I only want to show if the user is logged in, I was also planning on pulling a stripe customer Id from firebase to add into my orderData object. Everything was working perfectly until I changed routes back to a product page and returned to the checkout. When I do that the user is logged out, the form is gone and the stripeId from the user$ subscription is gone. I have the same logic in my checkout as I do in my header.

Checkout.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="!(auth.user$ | async)">Please register</div>

<form [formGroup]='orderForm' *ngIf="auth.user$ | async">...</form>
```

In my checkout component I am subscribed to the user$ and console log the value in ngOnInit(). When I do this, on page refresh, two values are printed and when I change routes and return nothing is printed.

```
constructor(
  public auth: AuthService,
  public stripePayment: PaymentService,
  private cart: CartService
  ) { 
   //this.auth.user$.subscribe( user => this.userData = user)
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.user$.subscribe( data => console.log(data) )
    }
```

I have tried creating methods in the authService and the component for retrieving and extracting the data and either it works on first page load or only when returning from a route change.

I did try changing my code in the auth service to change take(1), this made the order form work. After route changes and on log in. However the header component stopped working and the user information would not change on login.

```
user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
      private db: AngularFirestore,
      private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      ) { 

  this.user$ = fireAuth.authState.pipe(
take(1),
switchMap(user => {
  if (user) {
    return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
  } else {
    return of(null);
  };
})


 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippets looks perfect except for this one.

You are using the `user$` subscription in 2 components: Header and Checkouts. The Header component will work fine for all cases beacuse the component will always be there at the top of your page irrespective of the route you are in (my assumption from your question). But the Checkouts component will only be shown when you navigate to that page. Here comes the interesting part, the `user$` obseravble would have emitted the details of user as soon as he/she logs in and during this time Checkouts component is not even displayed and hence the component wouldn't have been created and it wouldn't have subscribed to `user$` observable. `user$` won't replay the last value when Checkouts component is created and subscribes to it. Hence you are not seeing the details of logged-in user here.

So you have to use a [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) to capture the details of logged in user. The main reason to use ReplaySubject here is that it can replay the some of the old emitted values to the new subscriber. Let's see how this can be done below.

**AuthService**

```
// ...
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
// ...

export class AuthService {
  // Create a ReplaySubject to store the history of logged in users
  private loggedInUsersSubject = new ReplaySubject<firebase.User>(1);

  // user$ is now returns an obseravble for the history subject
  get user$(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.loggedInUsersSubject.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    // do not store the fireAuth observable in user$
    // Instead push new logged in users to the ReplaySubject
    fireAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        };
      })
    ).subscribe(user => {
      // console.log(user);
      // Push the details of logged in user to ReplaySubject
      this.loggedInUsersSubject.next(user);
    });
}
```

As shown in the above code snippet, we are using a Replay Subject with a buffer size of 1 so that it can store the last emitted value. Now any new subscribers will get the last emitted value on subscription.

Header component should work fine as before. But now the Checkouts component will also capture the details of logged-in user and display it without any changes in the code.

**P.S:**

Remove all rxjs operators and experimentation you did from Checkouts component for the above solution to work. Also subscribe to `user$` observable in `ngOnInit()` method in Checkouts component and not in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for a few days. I tried the replay subject but I neither implemented the buffer size nor subscribed and pushed the user value to the ReplaySubject  with .next(). I have a better understanding of this concept now. I appreciate your help.